# Retrieving the code inside a 'with' statement

Tags: python, class, with-statement

INGORE THIS QUESTION
I clearly didn't explain well at all and none of the answers seemed to be on-topic for what I had in mind.

---

In the example shown below, I am trying to make a more concise loop where it will eventually look like `l(n)`, `l*n` or something similar.

In the example shown, the code will print `"hello"` 5 times (or whatever I set it to be) and then execute the code within the `with` loop, which is not unexpected.

However, the idea is the loop the code shown (`pass` in this case). How can I replace `print("hello")` with the code written within the with statement? Is it possible? I suppose that this isn't what a `with` statement should be used for so is there an alternative?

```py
class loop:
    def __init__(self, loops):
        self.loops = loops
    def __enter__(self):
        for x in range(self.loops):
            print("hello")
    def __exit__(self, *args):
        pass

    
with loop(5):
    pass
```

EDIT:
Here is the edited code since I don't think I stated clearly enough what I was trying to do:

```py
class loop:
    def __init__(self, loops):
        self.loops = loops
    def __enter__(self):
        pass
    def __exit__(self, *args):
        pass

    
with loop(5):
    print("This will loop 5 times")

with loop(10):
    print("This will loop 10 times")
```

So at any point in the program I could simply type the bottom two lines with any code and it would work. Could I make this work?

Comment: Why not `for _ in range(5):`?

Comment: Override `__nonzero__` and do `while loop(5):`

Answer (score 3):

I would avoid creating a class at all if you just want a  concise loop.

```
def loop(n):
    for _ in range(n):
        print("Hello")
        # Or whatever you want


loop(5)
```

Answer (score 0):

I don't think you can loop through the code inside `with` block. 
The closest thing would be to pass lambda as a second parameter.

```
class loop:
    def __init__(self, loops, action):
        self._loops = loops
        self._action = action
    def __enter__(self):
        for x in range(self._loops):
            self._action()
    def __exit__(self, *args):
        pass

def f():
    print("hello")

with loop(5, f):
    pass
```

Though you don't need `with` at all in this case:

```
def loop(n, f):
    for _ in range(n):
            f()

def my_printer():
    print("hello")

loop(5, my_printer)
```

Also I would avoid creating you own methods for loops, language already has built in syntax to create loops, just you it directly:

```
def my_printer():
    print("hello")

for _ in range(5):
    my_printer()
```

Comment: Is it possible for you to elaborate on the answer? This just provides a solution but does not really help the user understand why it works.

Comment: I would reject any code like this I saw in a code review.

Comment: @Enthus3d It is just slightly modified code provided in the question. From my perspective it is pretty straightforward and doesn't need any explanations. You you think it needs explanation, feel free to modify the answer, stackoverflow allows to to that and I think even encourages.

Comment: @chepner  I would also block such code in review (but not "reject" though as it means something different). Though I believe the question was about how to pass function as a first class object into `loop` for the purpose of learning.

Comment: I wouldn't go so far as to edit your answer for that, I am just pointing it out so you're aware that people may find it less friendly if you give a code block without explanation, as it makes them look for the differences themselves, and could confuse them.

Comment: I agree that your answer is definitely adequate for answering the asker's question, and it's clean code, I just think it could have been better if you had given an explanation.

Comment: No, the question was how to access the body of a `with` block from the context manager (which you cannot do). This is a workaround, but that doesn't mean one should write code like this.

Comment: @Enthus3d I updated the answer. Have just noticed he wants to use `with` body to loop over. I don't think Python allows to call body directly.

Comment: @chepner Yep. The code is bad. But the question was not to assess the code quality. I believe it is more for learning purposes to find you what you can do with Python.

Answer (score 0):

Don't use a loop.

def loop(n):
    for _ in range(n):
        print("Hello")

loop(5)

Then this will print "Hello" 5 times.

Comment: Is there a way to do it more 'dynamically' for example a module that you can import that will allow it? Defining a function defeats the point of reducing the amount of code written.

Comment: for _ in range(n):

Comment: print(" Hello ")

Comment: @Doot Your `with l(n):` would only save 8 characters over `for _ in range(5)`, ignoring the code you would have to write to *define* `l` in the first place. Python already provides a concise, *obvious* way to do what you want.

Comment: Listen to Chepner^^^

Comment: I have updated the question as functions would not be much better than a for loop, as chepner said